# Screen Sharing on iOS devices

Tags: screen-sharing, ios

Can I share the screen of one iOS device with another iOS device from app? Is it possible to implement above functionality using iOS SDK? Does Apple allow this type of app? If anyone know about this, kindly let me know. Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Are you talking about VNCing (Remote Desktoping) into another iPhone and controlling it or just letting someone see what you are doing on your screen?

Comment: I don't know that there's any packaged software to do exactly this, but if you want it to be a view-only sort of thing, you could use AirPlay Mirroring to a Mac using [AirParrot](http://airparrot.com/), then use a VNC to share it from the Mac to the other iOS device. Quality wouldn't be great, and you couldn't interact with the device, but it's possible

Answer (score 2):

Some short answers to your questions:

1. There is no such app available in the App Store. Things may be different in the jailbreak universe
2. Up until last weeks I would have said "no, probably not". But Apple now has approved a screen recording app for iOS so it seems to be possible.
3. Nobody will know for sure until somebody writes such an app and sends it to Apple for verification